# Could not locate API; are you sure it's enabled? - WP REST API oAuth1

Tags: wordpress, rest, oauth, wp-api, oauth-1.0a

I am getting:

```
"Could not locate API; are you sure it's enabled?"
```

When I try to link client to WordPress via **WP REST API**.

I have installed & activated all necessary plugins and dependencies, including (WP-REST API, oAuth1 etc).

When I try `HEAD http://mywebsitelink`, it returns link with wp-json which indicates WP-API is working.

Also, when I try `wp oauth1 add`, it works fine and generates key and secret.

Any suggestion on how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: same problem here, 
I'm using wp-rest v2 beta
and the  authentication prop is showed at http://myserver.com/wp-json/
`authentication: {
oauth1: {
request: "http://myserver.com/oauth1/request",
authorize: "http://myserver.com/oauth1/authorize",
access: "http://myserver.com/oauth1/access",
version: "0.1"
}
}`

any hint please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [Client CLI](https://github.com/WP-API/client-cli) package to connect the client with the WP REST API then please be informed that the latest version of the OAuth1.0a plugin doesn't work with the Client CLI package.

However, you can use an HTTP client to generate token credentials and then connect to the server using the OAuth1.0a plugin.